# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/api/ConnectionException when trying to use twitter connector

Tags: java, twitter, mule, esb

I'm having the following error when i try to use the twitter connector in my mule app.

I already have mule-core in my dependencies (and in my ear). Actually, my dependencies looks just fine..

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-twitter</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
```

etc.. etc..

Here's the stack:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/api/ConnectionException
13:44:06,985 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.twitter.connectivity.TwitterConnectorConnectionFactory.makeObject(TwitterConnectorConnectionFactory.java:37)
13:44:06,985 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
13:44:06,985 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.twitter.connectivity.TwitterConnectorConnectionManager.acquireConnection(TwitterConnectorConnectionManager.java:315)
13:44:06,986 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.twitter.connectivity.TwitterConnectorConnectionManager.acquireConnection(TwitterConnectorConnectionManager.java:34)
13:44:06,986 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.twitter.process.ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.java:60)
13:44:06,986 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.twitter.process.ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.java:21)
13:44:06,987 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.twitter.process.RetryProcessInterceptor.execute(RetryProcessInterceptor.java:69)
13:44:06,987 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.twitter.connectivity.ManagedConnectionProcessTemplate.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessTemplate.java:35)
13:44:06,987 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.twitter.processors.UpdateStatusMessageProcessor.process(UpdateStatusMessageProcessor.java:150)
13:44:06,988 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
13:44:06,988 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
13:44:06,988 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
13:44:06,989 ERROR [stderr] ([].BATCH.stage1.02)    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.api.ConnectionException
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`org.mule.api.ConnectionException` is in:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-devkit-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Do you have this dependency in your POM?

Comment: It works. Thank you so much David. I thought that this class should be in mule-core because there's a package named org.mule.api too. I googled it a lot and didn't find about this devkit module anywhere. Thanks!